# Cant read vaules from JavaScript Object always undifined

Tags: javascript, json, express

I can't retrieve values from a JavaScript object.

I have tried several ways but I can't get it to work the usual way i now but i am pretty new in javaScript.

Thanks for your time and attention, if there is anything missing or you need some more information please contact me.

**The Object** form *consol.log(unpackedReq)*

```
{
 'mFile ': {
    name: 'test',
    data: { type: 'Buffer', data: [Array] },
    size: 4,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
    md5: '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
  }
}
```

My Code:

```
app.post('/single', async(req, res, next) => {
try {
    
    const unpackedReq = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.files));
    const file = unpackedReq.mFile

    console.log(unpackedReq)
    console.log(typeof(unpackedReq)) //object
    console.log(unpackedReq["mFile"].name) // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')


} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send('Error uploading file')
}
```

The Full error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
>     at /Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/app.js:25:42
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at /Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
>     at Function.process_params (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
>     at next (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
>     at jsonParser (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:119:7)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/lukasbronstering/VsCode/ftp-web-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Assuming you're using Multer (or similar `multipart/form-data` middleware), you should definitely not be stringifying `req.files`. Why _are_ you doing that?

Comment: The mFile key has a space at the end.

Comment: Just for the record, nothing here is JSON.

Comment: thank you for the answers.
@Pointy Why is this not JSON ?
I think it looks like a JSON format so I assumed it was a JSON.
Can you explain this so I know for next time .

Comment: @Phil That was an attempt to solve my problem.
But that is now removed again anyway thanks to the note

Comment: @Sniphs JSON requires that all property names be quoted with double quote characters, and also all string values. What you've got in your question are JavaScript object initializers. The syntax is similar, but not the same. A JavaScript object is not JSON until it is serialized with `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in object 'mFile ' and you're accessing it without space.

so you can just add the space while accessing your object like this `console.log(unpackedReq["mFile "].name)` or you could change your object. but i would recommend to change your object name

Comment: thank you for the answer.
I really have not seen that for four hours 